# No finished signal

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Doesn't ever hit the function `self.onFinished` through the `self.process.finished.connect()` signal.  I'd like to feed additional commands to the dialog once the process has finished.

```py
class UpdateDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):

    outputSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    errorSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(UpdateDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        uic.loadUi(os.path.join(os.environ.get("ROOT_PATH"), "testd.ui"), self)

        self.process = QtCore.QProcess()
        self.completed = False
        self.process.readyReadStandardOutput.connect(self.onReadyReadStandardOutput)
        self.process.readyReadStandardError.connect(self.onReadyReadStandardError)

    def onReadyReadStandardOutput(self):
        error = self.process.readAllStandardError().data().decode()
        self.plainTextEdit_st.appendPlainText(error)
        self.errorSignal.emit(error)

    def onReadyReadStandardError(self):
        error = self.process.readAllStandardError().data().decode()
        self.plainTextEdit_st.appendPlainText(error)
        self.errorSignal.emit(error)
    
    def run(self, command):
        self.plainTextEdit_st.clear()
        self.process.finished.connect(self.onFinished)
        self.process.start(command)
    
    def onFinished(self):
        self.completed = True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = UpdateDialog()
    dialog.show()
    dialog.errorSignal.connect(lambda error: print(error))
    dialog.outputSignal.connect(lambda output: print(output))
    dialog.run("git clone --progress https://github.com/myrepo/test.git C:\\test\\")
    if dialog.completed:
        print("test")
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

Qt works asynchronously through signals, that is, tasks are launched (such as the run method) that will be executed not immediately but an instant after the eventloop is executed, so when you evaluate dialgo.completed it has not even been completed. started the QProcess.

Qt works using the event-oriented programming paradigm so the logic is to implement a function that does something when something happens, for example you want to print a text when the finishes signal is triggered then that task must be done in the associated slot to the signal:

```py
def onFinished(self):
    print("test")
```

Sequential logic does not work directly in Qt so you will have to change the implementation to achieve what you want.

A similar alternative is:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = UpdateDialog()
    dialog.show()
    dialog.errorSignal.connect(print)
    dialog.outputSignal.connect(print)
    dialog.run("git clone --progress https://github.com/myrepo/test.git C:\\test\\")

    def handle_finished():
        print("test")

    dialog.process.finished.connec(handle_finished)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

OR:

```py
class UpdateDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):

    outputSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    errorSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    finished = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(UpdateDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        uic.loadUi(os.path.join(os.environ.get("ROOT_PATH"), "testd.ui"), self)
        self.process = QtCore.QProcess()
        self.process.readyReadStandardOutput.connect(self.onReadyReadStandardOutput)
        self.process.readyReadStandardError.connect(self.onReadyReadStandardError)
        self.process.finished.connect(self.finished)

    def onReadyReadStandardOutput(self):
        output = self.process.readAllStandardError().data().decode()
        self.plainTextEdit_st.appendPlainText(output)
        self.outputSignal.emit(output)

    def onReadyReadStandardError(self):
        error = self.process.readAllStandardError().data().decode()
        self.plainTextEdit_st.appendPlainText(error)
        self.errorSignal.emit(error)

    def run(self, command):
        self.plainTextEdit_st.clear()
        self.process.start(command)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = UpdateDialog()
    dialog.show()
    dialog.errorSignal.connect(print)
    dialog.outputSignal.connect(print)
    dialog.run("git clone --progress https://github.com/myrepo/test.git C:\\test\\")

    def handle_finished():
        print("test")

    dialog.finished.connec(handle_finished)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I recommend you read [Signals & Slots](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html) so that you understand more about how Qt works